# Django rest framework filter not working with foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I was following `django-filters` official docs: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class

I have setup `volume` with ForeignKey relationship `filter-volume`. i want to get filters of `volume` with `min_volume` and `max_volume` , but i'm getting wrong data whenever i execute the filters.

It would be great if anyone could figure out where i doing thing wrong.

models.py :

```
class Cuboid(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    volume = models.ForeignKey('FilterVolume', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class FilterVolume(models.Model):
    volume = models.IntegerField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.volume
```

filters.py

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from crud_api.models import Cuboid

class CuboidFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    min_volume = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="volume", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_volume = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="volume", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Cuboid
        fields = [
            'min_volume','max_volume'
        ]
```

views.py

```
class CuboidListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Cuboid
    queryset = Cuboid.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CuboidSerializer
    filterset_class = CuboidFilter
```

[image: Foreign key error]

Comment: how did you *"execute"* the filters?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  i've added the screenshot in my questions.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63388455/12578202) :)

Comment: Have you added filter backend in settings? Add this `filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)` to `CuboidListApiView` to check if this work.

Comment: @isAif  yes!  i added.. but still it not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **`field_name`** to **`volume__volume`** instead `volume`

```
class CuboidFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    min_volume = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="volume__volume", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_volume = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="volume__volume", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Cuboid
        fields = ['min_volume', 'max_volume']
```

Comment: It's not proper working as like before. when i'm passing `min_volume` and `max_volume`. it's showing wrong data.

Comment: I have created a repository: https://github.com/satyajitbarik/Cuboid-API . you can figure out here if i made any mistakes.

Comment: This solution will work as-is. You can look into [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0JXZ.png) if you want

Comment: Update: the `NumericRangeFilter` seems not working in your case. Try with `NumberFilter`

Comment: updating `NumericRangeFilter` to `NumberFilter` is still not proper working... It would be great if you can take a look at my remote repository, If you found any solutions then please give a pull request. :)

Comment: I couldn't see the usage of `NumberFilter` in your [repo](https://github.com/satyajitbarik/Cuboid-API/blob/master/crud_api/api/filters.py)

Comment: Now i have updated it in my [repo](https://github.com/satyajitbarik/Cuboid-API/blob/master/crud_api/api/filters.py) , i have no idea...why it's not proper working in my case.

Comment: use **`Cuboid.objects.all()`** instead [`Cuboid.objects.filter(status=1)`](https://github.com/satyajitbarik/Cuboid-API/blob/master/crud_api/api/views.py#L15)

Comment: I guess, that shouldn't be effect while mapping the data from database. cause by default `1` means that's `active` in database. although i updated to `Cuboid.objects.all()` even it's still not working in my case.

Comment: Then you are looking in a wrong perspective. How did you conclude that *"it is not working"*?

Comment: It's showing me wrong data while i execute the `volume-filters`. And i still did not found the solutions yet.

Comment: It's proper working now when i changed the `related_name` on my `volume` field. thank you so much for your help :)